# React admin absolute redirectTo URL for OAuth 2 and OIDC

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, react-admin

I'm trying to connect my `react-admin` to `Keycloak`.

My `Keycloak` is listening on `https://accounts.domain.com`, while my `react-admin` is deployed on `https://admin.example.com`.

So as you can see they are deployed on two completely different hosts.

Now I don't want to see `login` form on `react-admin`.

In other words, since `keycloak` has everything, including all UIs, I want to redirect my user to `keycloak` instead of showing him the default `login` form of `react-admin`.

Thus in my `authProvider.js` I have this code:

```
const authProvider = {
    checkAuth: params => {
        // let's say user is not logged in
        return Promise.reject({
            redirectTo: 'https://accounts.domain.com'
        });
    }
}
```

However, when I go to my admin panel, it redirects me to `https://admin.example.com/#/https://accounts.domain.com`.

In other words, it seems that `react-admin` does not understand that this is an absolute URL.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you open an issue with a linked codesandbox?

Comment: @GildasGarcia, I tried to create a codesandbox, but I don't know why, it fails to build and tells me that it can's fetch dependencies. It's faily easy to reproduce. Just copying pasting all of the samples of docs would make it. The only difference is to use an external login page URL in `redirectTo` attribute.

Comment: @GildasGarcia, let's say it's a bug. Is there a workaround for this? I thought about manually forceing browser to my external login page via `windows.location` for example. But that breaks the concept of promises in `react-admin` and I have no idea if it breaks other things or not.

Comment: This bug was fixed in https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/6469, to be released in react-admin 3.18. I don't think there is a workaround.